# Cannot kill process shown in parenthesis

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I started a rather long `dd` command that I would like to stop.

`ps` shows:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 2006 ttys002    0:00.00 (dd)
```

The `dd` process is shown in parenthesis without the argument.

A `kill` produces no effect. Any idea on how to interrupt it?

Comment: Sure: directly in the shell `dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile size=...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual display of a process between `(…)` means this process was detached from its controlling terminal (here `ttys002`). This means that `^C`, `^\`, `^S`, `^Z` don't have anymore effect on it. It's behaving in *daemon* mode. This also means you can't send it a hangup either.

The correct way to deal with this case if unwanted, is to get
the number of its parent process with:

```
ps lw | egrep '[ ](2006|PID)'
```

and kill it with a hangup signal:

```
kill -HUP xxxx
```

where xxxx is the process ID of the parent process.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). Here's how to get rid of it from this answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/390552/how-to-kill-a-zombie-process-on-a-mac):

> > **Sadly**, it appears that killing of zombies is all about **killing the parent**, and if the parent is `/sbin/launchd`, you can kill it only with rebooting.
>
> It would be a Very Bad Idea to kill `launchd`, but you can tell it to HUP.
>
> Try `sudo kill -s HUP 1`
>
> That will cause launchd to reinitialize without restarting. This has worked for me in the past (wrt. removing zombie entries).

Comment: Are you sure? Zombie processes should be marked with a `Z` and in this case the `dd` process finished and was removed in the process table,

Comment: What does `ps aux` shows in STAT column?

Comment: The process finished after one hour (and produced the correct output) and I cannot check anymore ...

Comment: I don't know the other reason why process could not be killed and is shown in parenthesis in `ps` command. Maybe someone else have a clue.

Comment: Yes, but I answered too late.

Comment: @Mateusz: this wasn't a zombie, this was a daemon, and I won't be able to help understand why.